# What happens with crown chests crowns when chest is not unlocked?

Tags: clash-royale

To unlock the Crown chest, you need to get 10 crowns within a day. For each day I have played so far, I managed to get this (most of the time easily). However, today is the first day I will not manage to reach this limit. I am at 8 (of 10) right now, and I do not have the time to play a game (yes, I *do* have the time to post this question).

I don't mind that I cannot open the crown chest for today, but I am probably busy tomorrow as well. Do I have to start from scratch, or can I continue with 8 chests, and skip a day?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As far as I know from my experience and the [wiki](http://clashroyale.wikia.com/wiki/Chests), your chest will remain at 8/10 until you unlock it, and since it would have been more than 24 hours after the current chest was firstly available for unlock, you'll be able to unlock the next chest as well. (Not entirely sure for the one after that though)

So you will:

1. Be able to unlock your current chest with only 2 crowns.
2. Be able to unlock the next chest with 10 crowns immediately after you are done with 1.
3. Wait 24 hours after completing 1. to unlock any subsequent crown chest (and carry on as usual).

Comment: Yep, it stays as 8/10 until you reach 10/10 and if the 24 hours has been passed then you can instantly start collecting crowns for the next chest!  answer +1'd ~Jay

Comment: Cool, that means I haven't 'lost' a day if I find a few minutes in between somewhere

Comment: I think you'd have to go more than 2 days to lose progress.  The cool down timer will definitely start counting down on the second day as soon as it rolls over - so you can start work on the "day 2" crown chest immediately.  I believe free chest work the same way (even after 8 hours and two chests waiting, still earning time toward a 3rd once the two are collected.)

Comment: @EBongo afaik the timer for the third free chest is *not* running, when there are two chests waiting to be opened. I assume this Crown chest is the same. (I verified this answer yesterday, by playing the game on day 2. I indeed unlocked the first chest, and could continue immediately with the second chest. Unlocked them both)

Comment: @Mathias711 With respect to the Free Chests, you are right.  I don't know why I ever convince myself otherwise.  I play the game so much its rare for me to stack 2 frees, sadly.