# How many Crown Chests can be stacked up at one time?

Tags: clash-royale

Sometimes after opening a Crown Chest it displays a 24 hour timer. Sometimes it doesn't display a timer after opening and directly allows me to earn crowns again to open the next Crown Chest. This makes me think that the maximum is 2 chests, however I can't seem to find evidence on the internet for this.

**How many Crown Chests can be stacked up at one time?**

Comment: Check this out also http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/261364/what-happens-with-crown-chests-crowns-when-chest-is-not-unlocked/261366#261366

Answer (score 1):

You can only earn 1 crown chest per 24 hours. In the first day, if you earn a crown chest, the time resets to *24 hours left*. But if you don't, it will add the next 24 hours in its timer of 1 crown chest/ per day. That means you can earn 2 crown chests the next day.
Also you can only stack up 1 crown chest at a time.